# How to disable an SWT selectionListener until a separate thread has been completed

Tags: java, multithreading, swt, listener

I have an application with a GUI thread and a SQL thread.  There's a tree displayed in the GUI, and clicking on an item in the tree will launch a separate thread that will launch an SQL query.  Once the query is complete, the tree is updated.

The problem is, if the user clicks again on the tree before the fetching thread is complete, the tree will update before it has a chance to finish fetching the data and the tree will be updated incorrectly.  Is there any way to disable the listener just prior to launching the other thread, and then re-enabling it after the thread has been completed to prevent spurious inquiries?

```
private SelectionListener getTreeListener() 
{               

    //main tree listener that populates folder and report objects on the left side of the SashForm
    SelectionListener l = new SelectionAdapter() 
    {


        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0) 
        {

            Thread runThread = new FetchTreeChildrenThread(_es,_mgr,_PAI,_PE,_SelectedPub,Selected_Tree_Item);
                    runThread.start();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 1):

The fetch code needs to provide a callback that is called from within the 'SQL thread' after the query completed.

Then the UI code can register such a callback to re-enable the tree after the query was executed.

For example (within the `widgetSelected` method):

```java
Display display = new Display();
Runnable uiUpdateCode = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if( !tree.isDisposed() ) {
      // re-attach selection listner
    }
  }
};
Runnable doneCallback = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if( !display.isDisposed() ) {
      display.asyncExec( uiUpdateCode );
    }
  }
};
Thread backgroundThread = new Thread( new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    // ... execute query
    doneCallback.run();
  }
} );
backgroundThread.start();
```

Note that SWT only allows code that is executed on the UI thread to manipulate widgets. Therefore, `display.asyncExec()` schedules the given runnable to be executed on the UI thread 'at the next reasonable opportunity'.

Also note that at the time the runnable is invoked, widgets that have the may have been disposed of. Therefore, it is necessary to check for this case inside the runnable before accessing the widget.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than mess with whether or not the listener is enabled, you could just keep track of the thread you start and not start another one until the previous one finishes.

See [Thread.isAlive()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isAlive--)

```
private SelectionListener getTreeListener() 
{
    //main tree listener that populates folder and report objects on the left side of the SashForm
    SelectionListener l = new SelectionAdapter()
    {
        private Thread runThread;

        @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent arg0)
        {
            if (runThread == null || (!runThread.isAlive()))
            {
                runThread = new FetchTreeChildrenThread(_es,_mgr,_PAI,_PE,_SelectedPub,Selected_Tree_Item);
                runThread.start();
            }
        }
    }
}
```